# How can I write the fsum foldable function in haskell?

Tags: haskell, monoids, foldable

```
fsum :: (Foldable f, Num a) ⇒ f a → a
```

It computes the sum of all numbers in a container-like data structure.
My problem is that I cannot define `f a` as a list or `Maybe` or any other foldable types to have access. So I am assuming I should write

```
fsum x = ....
```

But I have no clue how to fold it given that `a` is not a monoid.
Any opinions?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Indeed you need to use `fsum x = ...` and you can't pattern match on `x` -- but you can use the [methods of the `Foldable` class](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#t:Foldable) like `foldr` and `foldl`, so ... (well, even `sum` is a method but I think you want to avoid that).

Comment: Thanks it finally clicked after two hours :)

Comment: In general, it if you only assume `Foldable f`, you have to use methods of the `Foldable` dataclass to operate on `f`.

Answer (score 0):

This was already answered in the comments. But here is some sample code:

```hs
main = do
  putStrLn $ show $ fsum [0,1,2]
  putStrLn $ show $ fsum (Just 4)

fsum :: (Foldable f, Num a) => f a -> a 
fsum = foldr (+) 0
```